# custom query with propel symfony 2

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, symfony, propel

This is my first time using symfony 2. For database integration i am thinking of using propel as I doctrine and annotations seems really difficult for me. But it seems to me that to make a query you have to use propels own functions. I have used codeigniter. In codeigniter I used to send query string and it used to send me data. Is there something similar in propel symfony 2?
Like -

```
$query = 'select * from table where column1 natural join column2';
$this->db->query($query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at docs of sf2:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/propel.html

If you want to use raw SQL:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT something FROM somethingelse");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Or "propel way":

```
$connection = Propel::getConnection();
$query = 'SELECT MAX(?) AS max FROM ?';
$statement = $connection->prepareStatement($query);
$statement->setString(1, ArticlePeer::CREATED_AT);
$statement->setString(2, ArticlePeer::TABLE_NAME);
$resultset = $statement->executeQuery();
$resultset->next();
$max = $resultset->getInt('max');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But why have you used getDoctrine? And I can't find anything about it in the link you have given me :(

Comment: Can you use parameterisation to specify a column or table name? I seem to recall reading it would have trouble with that, and that it is explicitly for values only.